# Oracle 10g Select in Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to formulate a query that returns the `vin`, `customer_id` and `model_id` where the **same** `customer_id` has **multiple** records that have a `model_id` of "*toyota*" from the `CAR` table. The `vin` in the primary key and unique. Any ideas?  I'm using Oracle 10g.

**CAR Table:**

```
vin varchar (primary key)
customer_id varchar
model_id varchar
```

**Data:**

```
vin        customer_id   model_id 
------------------------------------  
222313XYZ,   cust1234,   toyota
123232SSS,   cust1234,   toyota
111111ERE,   cust1111,   bmw
999999LKO,   cust1224,   bmw
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fdae/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE car
    (vin varchar2(9), customer_id varchar2(8), model_id varchar2(6))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO car (vin, customer_id, model_id)
         VALUES ('222313XYZ', 'cust1234', 'toyota')
    INTO car (vin, customer_id, model_id)
         VALUES ('123232SSS', 'cust1234', 'toyota')
    INTO car (vin, customer_id, model_id)
         VALUES ('111111ERE', 'cust1111', 'bmw')
    INTO car (vin, customer_id, model_id)
         VALUES ('999999LKO', 'cust1234', 'bmw')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**: in case you want to see **all** models whose owners also own more than one toyota

```
select vin, customer_id, model_id from (
 select vin, customer_id, model_id, 
 count( decode(model_id, 'toyota', 1) ) over (partition by customer_id) cnt
  from car
)
where cnt > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fdae/1/0)**:

```
|       VIN | CUSTOMER_ID | MODEL_ID |
--------------------------------------
| 999999LKO |    cust1234 |      bmw |
| 222313XYZ |    cust1234 |   toyota |
| 123232SSS |    cust1234 |   toyota |
```

**Query 2**: in case you want to see only toyotas whose owners own more than one of them:

```
select vin, customer_id, model_id from (
 select vin, customer_id, model_id, 
 count(*) over (partition by customer_id) cnt
  from car
 where model_id = 'toyota'
)
where cnt > 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fdae/1/1)**:

```
|       VIN | CUSTOMER_ID | MODEL_ID |
--------------------------------------
| 123232SSS |    cust1234 |   toyota |
| 222313XYZ |    cust1234 |   toyota |
```

Comment: that query seems to return model_id's other than toyota when I run it on my live data.

Comment: adding from car where model_id='toyota' seems to have fixed it, if you agree please update ur answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: my query is supposed to show all customers who own more than one toyota, regardless whether they own anything else or not. but if you want to see only toyotas, then yes, filter by model should be ok